# Temple Run 2 - Cannot pass the Slip n Sled Objective

Tags: temple-run-2

I have the Slip n Sled objective like this:

[image]

and as I read online this is the Ice Luge in Frozen Shadows:

[image]

as the Objective says you have to pass it 3 times in one run, but I see it only once on start. I have passed 10 000 meters in this Frozen Shadows map and it is not appearing again. Is there something special that I should do so this Ice Luge appears again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be quite rare, so you could have to go even 20k for the second one.

But you can use the **save me** and it will still be counted one run.

Answer (score 3):

First day or two I was on it, I had the same issue. That was within an hour of your your post. The next day the luges started showing up.